# Android: custom TableLayout not detect OnGestureListener.onFling(...)

Tags: android, gesture, custom-view

I have a custom `TableLayout` that has this code:

```
public class PageTableLayout extends TableLayout{

private static Context context;
private GestureDetector gDetector;

public PageTableLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    gDetector = new GestureDetector(context, gesture_listner);
}

public PageTableLayout( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ){
    super( context, attrs );
    this.context = context;
    gDetector = new GestureDetector(context , gesture_listner);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    Log(debug, "dispatchTouchEvent()");
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(me); 
    return gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
}

private OnGestureListener gesture_listner = new OnGestureListener(){
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log(debug, "onDown()..." );
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.(debug, "onFling()..." );
        .....
    }

    ...

 }
```

With this code i'm not able to detect the `onFling` event (it's not called!!!).. Any suggestion? If i put this `OnGestureListener` in an `Activity` it works!! `TableLayout` contains simple `TableRow` elements that contains `TextView`. Please help me..

Comment: Shouldn't you return `true` from `onDown`?

Comment: Yes.. that was the problem!! thank you Luksprog ..